# Collection of English sentence-level grammar rules as semi-structured "data"?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for structured data of English grammar, however much might have been done. Specifically sentence-level grammar (as opposed to word morphology rules, though finding structured data for both would be nice). By "structured data", I mean something more structured than grammar written in prose / natural language, ideally in a data format like JSON. Here is a hypothetical JSON data format for word morphology rules related to the English word "interconnected":

```
{
  name: 'ed',
  load: [
    { form: 'anchor', name: 'base', base: true },
    { form: 'pattern', name: 'consonant', test: 'consonant' },
    { form: 'anchor', head: false }
  ],
  save: [
    { name: 'base' },
    { name: 'consonant' },
    { text: 'ed' },
  ]
}

{
  name: 'inter',
  save: [
    { text: 'inter' },
    { name: 'self' }
  ]
}

{
  save: [
    { rule: 'inter' },
    { name: 'self' },
    { rule: 'ed' }
  ]
}
```

This is modeled after the Hunspell dictionaries, which are the main modern digital dictionaries used by OSes, browsers, etc.. The `load` takes a word from a dictionary and applies the rule to it. The `save` is the final generated word. So the `ed` rule says "base: true (meaning, read the first characters of the word), until the first consonant, where the consonant is the last letter. Then save the `base + consonant + ed`". The actual full Hunspell format entry is this:

```
SFX D Y 4
SFX D   0     d          e
SFX D   y     ied        [^aeiou]y
SFX D   0     ed         [^ey]
SFX D   0     ed         [aeiou]y
```

*Sidemote: Hunspell's format is a lot more compact and human readable, but it's a nightmare to parse, so the above JSON is closer to how a computer would perhaps model it after parsing the Hunspell format rule. But that is beside the point.*

This all just goes to show what I am looking for in terms of "structured data". JSON, XML, CSV, or some other data format would be perfect. The next best option is in raw code (which is pseudo-structured I would say, as it's better than natural language, but it's still hard to deal with and port to different places). [This](https://github.com/vinagrito/pealim/blob/57e3c473d89cce461ab82f1aa4b7ff5ff08b7622/lib/verb_constructor/paal.rb) huge pealim code file is for generating Hebrew verbs. It demonstrates what "code" would look like that I'm describing. And [this](https://github.com/words/double-metaphone/blob/f8f5dea33c9d71843d504349f1d46373ed5b2b74/index.js) code implements the "double metaphone" algorithm (a spell-check algorithm for English which is based on phonetics), it shows some code for dealing with English. Both demonstrate the point, that code would be a second-best option for structured data for English, after structured data.

So my question is, has anyone compiled (even the start of) a list of sentence-level grammar rules for English, in structured data form, as described? Or if not in structured JSON/etc., then as code? And if not code, what is the remaining last best bet, ideally some natural language text on a website, instead of a PDF or physical book.

*Mainly I am looking to build on top of it, and if nothing else, to gain inspiration on how to get started modeling sentence-level grammar rules in a structured way.*